# View Controller is not in window hierarchy issue?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, uiviewcontroller, hierarchy

I use storyboards, no navigation bar or tab bar. I'm using 2 view controllers and 2 storyboards for my app. ViewController has intro of game and ViewControllerTWO has actual game. I'm using ViewController and ViewControllerTWO for iPhone 4s and iPhone 5,5s.

ONLY when I load the iPhone 4s simulator, in the Debug Area, Xcode tells me "Warning: Attempt to present "GKHostedAuthenticateViewController: 0x8989e7e0 on ViewControllerTWO: 0x78974xc0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Also, when I plug in my iPhone 4s device, I don't get this message, it only gets this message when i'm using simulator for iPhone4s.

What does this mean? What's Xcode want with ViewControllerTWO?

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform your segue in `-viewDidAppear:`. The view controller can't present anything before its loaded into the main window.